# How to modify the contents (string) of an object within an array of objects using Array.each?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to fix particular fields within an array of objects:

```
@results.each do |result|
  ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8')
  clean_name = ic.iconv(result.name + ' ')[0..-2]
  result.name = clean_name
  if clean_name != result.name 
    puts "Name:    #{result.name} \ncleaned: #{clean_name}"
  end

end
```

And the server output:

```
Name:    Free Pretzel Day @ Auntie Anne?s 
cleaned: Free Pretzel Day @ Auntie Annes
```

This stemmed from getting the error "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8", so I found the iconv code to fix that.  In this case, I have an array of objects and I'm trying to clean up the `result.name` field. But, when I iterate over it and save it "`result.name = clean_name`" it doesn't actually seem to modify the object field `result.name`.

Comment: Well, I still haven't been able to solve this issue, but it seems to be around the fact that the result object is pulled from the rMeetup Gem and it seems that I can't modify these objects.  I checked if they were immutable via freeze? but that returns false so not clear to me why I can't modify the fields of this object.  I worked around the issue by dealing with the utf8 issue directly in the view and displaying the "clean_name" directly so I don't need to store it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ActiveRecord don't forget to save the record after updating the attribute

```
result.name = clean_name
result.save
```

or use the mor convenient update_attribute function which is saving implicitly

```
result.update_attribute(:name, clean_name)
```

But keep in mind that validations are skipped then.

Comment: So in this case I'm not using ActiveRecord or storing to any DB.  It's just a temporary array of objects.

Comment: Then I misunderstood. See my other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use map and return the individual result elements at the end of the block

```
@results.map do |result|
  ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8')
  clean_name = ic.iconv(result.name + ' ')[0..-2]
  result.name = clean_name
  if clean_name != result.name 
    puts "Name:    #{result.name} \ncleaned: #{clean_name}"
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: Hmm, yes map would work better here, thanks!  But the issue is that it does not even seem to be updating the local result object (i.e. the if loop should never execute, but it does) so I end up with the same original result.